# How to edit a group of selected features in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, features

I am dealing with a large number of planning units across a very large study area.  I am selecting a number of features using the advanced search in the attribute table, and would like to edit them (i.e. change their colour).  The only way I can think of doing it is to save the selected features as a new layer, and then edit that.  Is there an easier way?
Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Just FYI Matt, changing the color of the feature is not considered to be "editing" it, you are just changing the way the feature is displayed, the symbology of it. Editing it would involve changing either the shape/location of the feature, or changing its associated attributes, or both.

Comment: But what if it couldn't be solved symbologically? Suppose one were trying to edit a group of features' vertices.

Answer (score 7):

Matt: if the features have common attributes, you can theme them on those attributes. Check Properties > Style and choose Categorized or Rule-based and play around with the settings there.

Comment: perfect - exactly what I needed.  Thanks for your help